# Add a loading animation to a preload="none" Html 5 video while it loads

Tags: video, html

I am looking for a way to add a small animation to a video loading as a user hovers over a thumbnail.  Right now when a visitor hovers over a thumbnail they have no way of knowing that the video is loading.

Before I no preload="none" parameter in my movie and the resulted in HUGE load times, so now I set everything to Preload="none", but now there is no info that there is a movie there.

One idea I had was to add a video loading with a spinner or just the text loading while the video loads then then disappears when the video starts.

Is there any advice on this I could get or maybe point me in the right direction.

Here is my site: http://motion-master-templates.com

Thank you :)

Comment: This isn't a WordPress question, this is a html5/videos question, as such this probably isn't the best place to ask if you'd like an answer, perhaps the question could be moved to a site with more expertise in the field of html5 video?

Comment: Take a look at the FAQ. It shows you possible target network sites. I already flagged it for movement.

Comment: Thank you Tom and Kaiser,  I am using wordpress so I thought it was the right forum.

Comment: You need to write some JavaScript that handles this. The easiest solution is to just listen on the ``timeupdate`` event and start playing as soon as the ``paused`` flag is ``false``. This should get you most of the way, but beware that the different browser implementations of HTML5 audio and video still hasn't converged.